# Error 503 in OpenShift server

Tags: django, openshift

That's my first Django project and I'm trying to deploy it to OpenShift, but I have a problem: when I'm trying to open app's page, I see "503: Service Temporarily Unavailable" message. I thought that app wasn't started so I tried to launch 'ctl_app start' in ssh and I've got this:

```
python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried to start app this way: `rhc app start customerquiz` and got this:

```
RESULT:
customerquiz started
```

But it took no effect. Well, I tried to look the state of app:

```
$ rhc app show --state customerquiz
Cartridge python-2.7, mysql-5.1, phpmyadmin-3.4 is started
```

And that's what in server logs:

```
$ rhc tail customerquiz
==> mysql-5.1/log/mysql_error.log <==
130519 17:32:54 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130519 17:32:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/000005//mysql-5.1/pid/mysql.pid ended
130519 17:33:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/000005//mysql-5.1/data/
130519 17:33:04  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
130519 17:33:05  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130519 17:33:05  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130519 17:33:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130519 17:33:05 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.69'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/000005//mysql-5.1/socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution

==> python-2.7/logs/appserver.log <==
python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

==> phpmyadmin-3.4/logs/access_log-20130519-000000-EST <==
109.254.107.11 - - [19/May/2013:17:14:13 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/error.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&token=436aa&js_frame=right&nocache=5471357898" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
- - - [19/May/2013:17:14:13 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:14:18 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:14:19 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/main.php?token=436aa HTTP/1.1" 200 35472 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - adminB [19/May/2013:17:14:21 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/version_check.php?&_nocache=1368998062197204658 HTTP/1.1" 200 44 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/main.php?token=436aa" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:14:19 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?token=436aa HTTP/1.1" 200 5029 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:20:49 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:20:50 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?token=436aa HTTP/1.1" 200 5029 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:20:50 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/main.php?token=436aa HTTP/1.1" 200 35472 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
109.254.107.11 - admin [19/May/2013:17:20:52 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/version_check.php?&_nocache=1368998453881950766 HTTP/1.1" 200 44 "https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/main.php?token=8436aa" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"

==> phpmyadmin-3.4/logs/error_log-20130519-000000-EST <==
[Sun May 19 17:12:56 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun May 19 17:12:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 19 17:28:00 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c356
[Sun May 19 17:28:00 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun May 19 17:28:00 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[
Sun May 19 17:28:00 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 19 17:33:17 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c6,c356
[Sun May 19 17:33:17 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun May 19 17:33:17 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun May 19 17:33:17 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Does anyone have any ideas what can be wrong?

P.S. That's deployed project source code, if you need it: https://github.com/uncleLem/CustomerQuiz (I just changed database connection parameters).

P.P.S. Oh, BTW, if I open https://customerquiz-unclelem.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/ directly, I can see phpMyAdmin page.

Comment: They really need to document this stuff better. They switched servers without really making that obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not using mod_wsgi with these new carts. 2.7 uses gevent and 3.3 uses WebOb

Take a look at how we set up the app.py in the 2.7 cart
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-community-cartridge-python-2.7/blob/master/template/app.py

and for 3.3
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-community-cartridge-python-3.3/blob/master/template/app.py

Can you review the following blog post to see if it helps?
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/host-python-in-a-community-cart

Comment: May be I should just use openshift django template (https://github.com/openshift/django-example) and then add files from my project?

Comment: That's the best way to get started!

Comment: Well, I tried but now I have another problem. I created another question, may you look it, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725903/django-importerror-no-module-named-quiz-views

Comment: I will check it out later!